# How to move the database from internal memory to external memory?

Tags: android, database, sd-card

I'm storing few sms messages and their details in a database.  By default the database is stored in internal memory.  I would like to check for the internal memory before accessing the database and once it is full I would like to move the database to external memory.  How to handle this?

Comment: I pretty sure this is possible, but before I post a complete answer I want you to know that it's not recommended for security reasons. Databases are stored in internal memory so they can't be extracted from your phone. Any app can access external memory but only your app can access internal memory reserved for your app. P.S. By extracted I mean, you can copy anything from the external memory. People can grab it from an app, send it over the internet and inspect it from their own computer, if they wanted.

Comment: but what if the internal memory becomes full?

Comment: That's really up to the user, most databases don't take up that much space esp in Android. I couldn't see you getting above a couple MB storing messages that are 160 chars long, dates, recipients, etc. I mean unless you're storing more than like several thousand. Also think about storing the information in an xml file, like Faisal Saleem said. It's more more acceptable to store an xml file in the external memory, but no one really stores databases there.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much not sure about what you exactly doing up there. Whereas what I do is, there is an app in android market name sms backup and restore. Just run that utility which will save your messages in a xml file in the external storage sd-card. You can move the file wherever you want and xml can be read and write easily too. You can even restore the xml file with the same application to any other android device or into your own device.